# Quelle est la fonction de "que" suivi par un substantif ?

Tags: grammaire, questions

On lit des phrases comme

> Qu'est-ce qu'un ... ?

ou

> Ce que c'est que la mort

mais ce deuxième "que" comment fonctionne-t-il et quel est son sens précis ? Est-ce un cas qui n'est pas possible d'être traduit précisément en autres langues ? En anglais, je dirais "What is that '...'?" ou "What is a '...'?", mais cela en francais serait quelque chose comme "Qu'est-ce un ... ?", omettant le "que".

De plus, à [larousse.fr](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/que/65601), quel est le sens dédié à ce cas d'utilisation parce que je ne l'ai pas trouvé là.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**
Voici la transcription en syntaxe explicite que l'on trouve p. 64 (pdf) de l'article « [Que complétif en français : essai d'analyse](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2008-2-page-53.htm#) ». L'auteur nous dit et montre que dans la langue parlée il existe 3 degré d'interrogation.

> Qu’est-ce que c’est que ça ? (que ce truc-là ?, que la métempsycose ?)
>   = « (1 quoi est (2 ce que est (3 ce que ça [est] 3) 2) ? 1) »

On peut lire p. 67 de l'article cité que le mot « que » a la fonction grammaticale d'attribut du sujet dans la proposition complétive.

Il est bon de s'informer de la récapitulation suivante de l'auteur de l'article (dans sa conclusion, même page), qui serait la révélation d'une mise au point corrigeant les misconceptions du monde grammatical français en ce qui concerne cette construction :

> " Au total, si les hypothèses développées ci-dessus sont exactes, nous pensons
>   avoir montré que le « que » complétif est un pronom neutre, instrument d’une opération abstraite de nominalisation. Il n’est donc pas ‘vide’ comme le dit toute la
>   tradition grammaticale et linguistique, et il n’y a pas de ‘conjonction pure’ ou
>   de ‘connecteur pur’ : la fonction de connexion n’est pas exclusive d’une appartenance catégorielle et d’une fonction (elle en est peut-être même inséparable).
>   Le « que » complétif a une fonction (attribut) dans l’ensemble subordinatif qu’il
>   introduit, ensemble dans lequel la structure ‘P’ (à laquelle « que » reste extérieur)
>   est sujet, la copule restant sous-jacente sans perdre son efficience. ".

**II**

L'aspect syntaxique ayant été dégrossi ci-dessus, quelques détails sur l'aspect sémantique pourraient être d'intérêt.

Selon LBU 14 ième ed., pg. 507, § 402 c), il faut considérer "**(qu'est-)ce que c'est que**" en tant que locution exclamative dans certains cas, c'est à dire lorsque une proposition indépendante se termine par un point d'exclamation et que la locution est au début. Cela signifie que l'analyse grammaticale de « que » n'a pas un intérêt bien grand pour la compréhension, mais elle est la même que dans le cas de l'interrogation ou d'une connexion à une principale.

Lorsque la phrase est une interrogation — une seule des deux variantes est alors utilisée : « Qu'est-ce que c'est que… » — l'analyse est plus intéressante et la tournure relève de la langue parlée.

La forme exclamative « ce que c'est que … »,  n'est utilisée que dans le sens de communiquer de l'admiration, de l'effroi, de l'émerveillement. C'est aussi une forme qui seule et sans le point d'exclamation est utilisée pour des titres ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mIspDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT15&dq=%22ce+que+c%27est+que%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK4te0gMrkAhUNzoUKHXHnA68Q6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22ce%20que%20c'est%20que%22&f=false)). La forme « qu'est-ce que c'est que… » est aussi utilisée pour communiquer de l'admiration, etc., mais est moins effective dans ce but ; elle est utilisée en plus pour en premier lieu exprimer tout simplement des questions, en cela naturellement prédisposée par sa syntaxe, et ensuite pour exprimer de fortes critiques, des désapprobations, et dans ces cas-là le substantif est souvent déterminé par un démonstratif ; la différence dans la langue parlée est le plus souvent accompagnée par une différence dans le ton sur lequel est faite la prononciation (aspect important dans la prononciation).

- … qu'est-ce que c'est que cette justice qui découvre des preuves d'une condamnation deux ans après l'arrêt rendu, et qui nous produit comme convaincantes des pièces qui n'ont pas été soumises à l'accusé! (CLEMENCEAU, L'Iniquité, 1899, p. 206.)
- Lieu agité et bruyant; lieu où règnent le désordre et la confusion. Quel souk! qu'est-ce que c'est que ce souk! L'autre hideux là-haut, dans son souk, il devait roupiller toujours.  (CÉLINE, Mort à crédit, 1936, p. 474)

Answer (score -1):

*Qu'est ce qu'un bidule = Qu'est ce **qu'un bidule [est]**.*

*Ce que c'est que la mort = Ce que c'est **que la mort [est]**.*

Comme tu peux le voir, nous avons en fait une authentique proposition relative dont le verbe (être) a été effacé.
De toutes les manières, ce deuxième *être* n'étant que dans sa fonction de copule n'apportait aucun sens.

Il s'ensuit que ce deuxième *que* qui t'intrigue n'est autre qu'un **pronom relatif**, COD de la principale et sujet de la relative.

On retrouverait ce même *que* dans d'autres constructions du genre :

*Triste réponse **que** celle-là [est]* ;-)

Puisque nous n'avons donc plus formellement de proposition en tant que telle (pas de verbe explicité), certains préfèrent dire ce *que* ***déclaratif*** ou ***complétif***.

Comment: Ces constructions ne sont pas des relatives, elles sont généralement appelées mises en relief ou clivées. Elles permettent de placer un constituant quelconque en tête de phrase entre « c'est » et « que ». Par exemple, c'est pour cette raison que cette construction n'est pas une relative...

Comment: [Mise en relief/phrase clivée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphase_(linguistique)#Extraction_ou_phrase_cliv%C3%A9e)

Comment: @GAMPUB : J'entends bien. Et donc ? Quelle est la fonction (grammaticale) de ce *que* en tant que la question était posée ?

Comment: Dans votre analyse il ne peut pas être question de COD : c'est une construction où on trouve seulement le verbe « être » ; de plus, « que » est attribut du sujet, ce sujet étant « la mort » :  « Ce que **ce** est **que**  la mort est » ; la mort est quelque chose (que), la mort est « que ».

Comment: Voir par exemple ceci, niveau 67 ou p. 60 du pdf : https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2008-2-page-53.htm#

Comment: Pas de COD ici.